# Undeclared identifier when passing struct using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, readline, stringtokenizer

I have the following method to read a file into a struct, but, the program is bombing when it gets to the write file method as the `curr` variable is empty.

I have added a null check when the variables are tokenized but, its not throwing an error at that point. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I have copied the data to the `newContact` but I cant see where I'm messing up.

This is the method mentioned that reads in the file tokenizes the variables and adds the `newContact`:

```
struct contact *readFile(char * FName,struct contact** ptrList)
{    
    struct contact *head, *newContact;
    FILE *fptr;
    char oneLine[60];
    char *sname, *fname, *phone,*company, *email;

    head = *ptrList;

    fptr = fopen(FName,"r");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCant open file!");
        return(ptrList);    
    }
    fgets(oneLine, 55, fptr);
    while(!feof(fptr))
    {
        fgets(oneLine, 55, fptr);
        if(oneLine[strlen(oneLine)-1] == '\n')
        {
            oneLine[strlen(oneLine)-1] = '\0';    
        }

        // open file and other stuff
        if(!ptrList) return; // invalid pointer
        for(head=*ptrList;head&&head->next;head=head->next);
        while( ReadLine(fptr,oneLine) )
        {
            //check that variables aren't empty here:
            if(sname == NULL || fname == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nvariable empty!");
                //return(ptrList);
            }
            sname = strtok(oneLine,",");
            fname = strtok(NULL,",");
            phone = strtok(NULL,",");
            company = strtok(NULL,",");
            email = strtok(NULL,",");

            newContact = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
            if(!newContact) break; // out of memory
            newContact->prev = head;
            newContact->next = 0;

            //copy the data to the new one
            strcpy(newContact->sname,sname);
            strcpy(newContact->fname,fname);
            strcpy(newContact->phone,phone);
            strcpy(newContact->company,company);
            strcpy(newContact->email,email);

            head = newContact;
            if(!*ptrList) *ptrList = head; // see: point 2
        }
    }
```

This is the `struct` declaration:

```
struct contact {
    char sname[15];
    char fname[15];
    char phone[15];
    char company[15];
    char email[15];
    struct contact *prev;
    struct contact *next;
};
```

I'm also getting an undefined error here at `ReadLine`. Is there a library I should import for this function (as I can't see any mentioned in a search)?

```
while( ReadLine(fptr,oneLine) )
```

The new error occurs here:

```
head = *ptrList;
```

Any ideas as to why it's bombing?

Comment: ReadLine is not defined or declared.

Comment: Yes but is there an import for ReadLine as its a funtion?

Comment: It might be good idea to show the code where the crash occurrs.

Comment: gnu readline ? Although the case will be different, `readline` vs `ReadLine`

Comment: And it serves a different purpose. Why `ReadLine`, are you sure you're not mixing it up with a function from some other language?

Answer (score 0):

```
head = newContact;
if(!*ptrList) *ptrList = head; // see: point 2
```

I believe , you are already at the end of the list .
I do not see the need for this 'if' statement. We are never changing the actual 'head' of the list and this is where 'ptrList' is pointing to.

Also, don't you want the below 'for' loop outside of first while loop?
The code is trying to read from a file and add to the end of a list.
I don't see the need to traverse the loop for every line of file.

```
 for(head=*ptrList;head&&head->next;head=head->next);
```